# Using LINQ to iterate through a database and generate a generic XML layout of schema + data

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml, database-schema

Is there an easy way to have LINQ iterate through each of the fields in a table and get field properties such as the field name? Basically, I want to just create a simple xml document that represents the db schema like so:

```
 <report>
      <nameoffirsttable>
           <field1name>field1data</field1name>
           <field2name>field2data</field2name>
           ...
           <field234name>field234data</field234name>
      </nameoffirsttable>
      <nameofsecondtable>
           ...
      </nameofsecondtable>
      <anothersecondtable>
           ...
      </anothersecondtable>
 </report>
```

So far, all the examples I have seen in web searches have shown explicit references to named fields.

Comment: A `System.Data.DataSet` has methods `WriteXml` and `WriteXmlSchema` that can write out tables in a DataSet as XML. That is not LINQ obviously so I mention it in a comment, not as an answer, but maybe it suffices for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce the schema you outlined using LINQ:

```
XElement report = new XElement("report", 
MyDataContext.Mapping.GetTables()
   .Select(i => 
      new XElement(i.TableName, 
          i.RowType.DataMembers
          .Select(j => new XElement(j.Name, j.DeclaringType.Type.Name))));
```

Just make sure to reference System.Data.Linq and System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice example of how to iterate through the schema.  Still kinda tricky to also correlate the data, instead of using the field's table name (j.DeclaringType.Type.Name).  However answered my question and helped me know what to search for!